# What to use instead of the dsearch function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I'm looking at an old code in MATLAB, which I want to modify. The issue is, the code contains the function dsearch, which as far as I understand has been discontinued. Is there a function that can replace it? If not, what code should I write to make it do the same thing as dsearch?

Answer (score 1):

Use `dsearchn`.  As suggested by Mike (23-Sep-2013) in the [comments thread for Darren Engwirda's MESH2D](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25555-mesh2d-automatic-mesh-generation), `tsearch` can be replaced by `tsearchn`.  Likewise, `dsearch` can be replaced by `dsearchn`.

Note that a slight change in usage is required. `dsearch` works only for 2D triangulations, while `dsearchn` works for n-dimensional triangulations.  Therefore, instead of

`k = dsearch(x, y, t, xi, yi);`

you should use

`k = dsearchn( [x,y], t, [xi, yi] );`